# Exercise 26 of The Pragmatic Programmer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, law-of-demeter

There is a code snippet presented in [*The Pragmatic Programmer*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) on page 143 as:

```
public class Colada {
    private Blender myBlender;
    private Vector myStuff;

    public Colada() {
        myBlender = new Blender();
        myStuff = new Vector();
    }
    private doSomething() {
        myBlender.addIngredients(myStuff.elements());
    }
}
```

This obeys the Law of Demeter / Principle of Least Knowledge.

Is it preferable to, and are there any caveats for, replacing it with the following, which utilises Dependency Injection?

```
public class Colada throws IllegalArgumentException {
    private Blender myBlender;
    private Vector myStuff;

    public Colada(Blender blender, Vector stuff) {
        if (null == blender) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException()
        } else {
            myBlender = blender;
        }
        if (null == stuff) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException()
        } else {
           myStuff = stuff;
        }
    }

    public static Colada createDefaultInstance() {   
        Blender blender = new Blender();
        Vector stuff = new Vector();

        return new Colada(blender, stuff);
    }

    private doSomething() {
        myBlender.addIngredients(myStuff.elements());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that abuse of `?:`?  Don't you think it would be more readable written out as if-else statemens?

Comment: Methods called `getInstance` usually have to do with singletons. I think that `createDefaultInstance` is more appropriate. Cheers

Comment: I like the IllegalArgumetnExceptions to be alone in an if, without an else.  Shows the intent better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you structure **creation** of objects are a separate concern than the **API** it exposes.

The Law of Demeter says something about the API of classes, not how they are constructed, so I see no conflict between **Constructor Injection** and the Law of Demeter.

That said, once you decide to use Dependency Injection, you should be careful to **avoid ambiguity** when it comes to creation of objects. If you keep offering a parameterless constructor or a static factory method, people may use this instead of letting the external caller compose the dependency hierarchy.

Every time developers accidentally break the dependency hierarchy by using the factory method (or paramterless constructor) they introduce a **tight coupling** at that point. When you decide to use DI, you can best harvest the benefits from doing so consistently.

Answer (score 2):

public getInstance(), shouldn't that be "public static Colada getInstance()"?

Both are fine in my world, the first one more readable, the second one more dynamic. But neither of them suggest that myBlender and myStuff are properties, thus it's hard to see why you'd prefer it dynamic. But if that's what you want, it looks all right. Instead of getInstance I'd just make two constructors, though, one with no arguments like the first example and one with two like the second

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Fixed the static factory method declaration. re:"it's hard to see why you'd prefer it dynamic." =>  It's habituation in regards to the ability to perform unit testing.